# Make new columns and headers from one column dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am loading in text files that only have one column, but multiple rows. The data in each column is a date in the format yyyy/mm/dd/hh. Is there a way to split this into 4 columns, with each header being the year, month, day and hour and put the associated values in the correct columns? I have hundreds of these files, with hundreds of dates each and it will be a major pain to hand organize them. For example:

```
Unnamed column
1998/12/16/06
2015/09/23/12

Year    Month    Day    Hour
1998    12       16     06
2015    09       23     12
```

Comment: What have you tried? `pandas` library could likely make this trivial for you

Comment: I've been looking around the pandas library, but can't find exactly what I need.

Comment: it might be as simple as `read_csv` and then `df["Unnamed column"].str.split("/", expand=True)`

Comment: Thanks, this worked.